# Configuring Apache VFS using config files

Tags: java, vfs, apache-commons-vfs

I'm using Apache VFS and am configuring the SFTP file system programatically like this...

```
    SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, true);
```

I want to be able to easily swap in different providers and not have to write code to configure a specific individual provider. Is there a way to set these options in the providers.xml file or some other file?